# Ionic / Angular big image list, scroll freezes

Tags: angularjs, performance, ionic-framework, scroll, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of links and images in my Ionic (1) app. I am using `collection-repeat` but it super slow!

I switched to a grid list, so our user can see the pictures better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnG5ZdC0NoA

[image: Grid list view]

In the video, whenever you see an item highlighting, it's my finger that can't "catch" the scroll...super annoying...

What could I do to improve the scroll and also the transition to this list view that is really long?

```
<div class="scrollContainer boardsTab">
            <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" overflow-scroll="false">
                <!-- <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="doRefresh()">
                </ion-refresher> -->
                <div class="loadingboards" ng-if="!transitionFinished">
                    <ion-spinner class="spinner spinner-ios">
                    </ion-spinner>
                    <br/>
                    Loading boards list...
                </div>
                <div class="boardselection firstScreen" ng-if="transitionFinished">
                    <ion-item collection-repeat="item in prodataSelect | orderBy:data.sort | filter: data.selectBrand.brand:true | filter: data.selectName.name | filter: generalSearchFunc | filterObj:['brand','modelStrict']" item-width="25%" item-height="35%" item-render-buffer="8">
                        <a class="optionfuninit item-content" data-proid="{{item.id}}" ng-click="whatToDo(item.id,$event);" ng-class="item.fun == '0' ? 'aNormal' :( item.fun == '1' ? 'aSmallWave' : (item.fun == '2' ? 'aStepUp' : ''))">
                            <div class="listviewTrophy" ng-if="isWinning(item.id)">
                                <i class="icon ion-trophy"></i>
                            </div>
                            <i class="icon ion-female" ng-show="item.gender == 'female'"></i>
                            <p class="flex-caption" fittext fittext-min="10" fittext-max="15" ng-bind="item.modelStrict" > 
                            {{item.modelStrict}}
                            </p>
                            <div class="imagebox">
                                <img class="imageoptionsmodel " ng-src="{{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}}"/>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </ion-item>
                </div>
            </ion-scroll>
        </div>
```

Comment: an idea would be to implement a paginable list and use "Infinite scroll" 

For example : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/ 

with ionic 2 ;)

Comment: Do you think it would be faster than  `collection-repeat` ?

Comment: You have to mixed them : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/what-about-mixing-collection-repeat-and-ion-infinite-scroll/4010

Comment: look  at comment of https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/864b46aa818c3a230e77225ab704c16acbc93ac5/js/angular/directive/collectionRepeat.js#L26-L58